# Crawl data with Scrapy to load more?

Tags: python, post, scrapy

I need to crawl some news from this site: https://www.huxiu.com/channel/103.html. Here 103 is the news category id.

But I can only get the first page if not triggering the ajax to load more: 
[image]
Very strange the request url is the same for different news categories.

[image]

And the page information was delivered by headers by the referer. And the page is sent by the form data.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    self.page += 1
    url = "https://www.huxiu.com/channel/ajaxGetMore"
    method = "POST"

    headers = {
        "Host": "www.huxiu.com",
        "Origin": "https://www.huxiu.com",
        "Referer": "https://www.huxiu.com/channel/106.html",
        "User-Agent": (
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/"
            "537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Sa"
            "fari/537.36"
        ),
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

    formdata = {
        "huxiu_hash_code": "9aee58d3507ecafed74df13e156ab01b",
        "page": str(self.page),
        "catId": "106"
    }

    yield FormRequest(
        url=url,
        method=method,
        headers=headers,
        formdata=formdata,
        callback=self.parse
    )
```

Which failed to load more news feeds. How can I send the post request to crawl more news?

Comment: Is the hash code always the same if you inspect what you browser sends? Could it be that the hashcode is taken from the page itself?

Comment: The hashcode is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case GET and POST requests seem to be interchangable.
This is a very common AJAX pagination technique:

If you'd try: https://www.huxiu.com/channel/ajaxGetMore?catId=103&page=3 in your browser and you'd see some json data that contains all pagination data aswell as some meta data like `total_page`. This information is easy to crawl and allows you to crawl concurrently every page since you know page count from the very first request.

See for example how this spider for python3 deals with this sort of pagination:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter

class MySpider(Spider):
    start_urls = ['https://www.huxiu.com/channel/ajaxGetMore?catId=103&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        yield from parse_data(response)  # parse first page as well
        # yield async requests for every other page.
        for page in range(2, data['data']['total_page']):
            # make next page url by replacing page parameter
            url = add_or_replace_parameter(response.url, 'page', page)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        # parse json data
```